# Android setlistAdapter error

Tags: android

hi just getting an error and I'm not sure why can anyone help?

when i run it it forces the application to close. not sure what this means as i'm new but hopefully someone can help?

heres the error from the LogCat[image]

this is how my json feed is structured i want the news array

{"code":200,"error":null,"data":{"news":[{"news_id":"8086"
I'm getting an error here: in the oneOjectsItem

setListAdapter ( new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.single_item, oneObjectsItem));

here my code

```
        // Instantiate a JSON object from the request response
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);



        JSONArray jArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("news");


        for (int i=0; i < jArray.length(); i++)
        {
            JSONObject oneObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            // Pulling items from the array
            String oneObjectsItem = oneObject.getString("title");



        }


    } catch(Exception e){
        // In your production code handle any errors and catch the individual exceptions
        e.printStackTrace();
    }




    setListAdapter ( new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.single_item, oneObjectsItem)); 



ListView list = getListView();
list.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
            long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView) arg1).getText(),1000).show();
    }



});

}
```

Comment: String oneObjectsItem is defined and init'ed inside `for` loop. Is that really what you needed?

Comment: Probably, `oneObjectsTestItem` is `null`, could you please test this by logging it? In addition, there must be another delcaration of `oneObjectsItem` than that in the for loop because you access it from outside, can you find that second declaration?

Comment: thats what I'm strugglinging with on how to get it from the for loop to outside it. can you provide an example so i can better understand it

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that you have another declaration of  `String oneObjectsItem` which is not initialized. Then you create (by mistake?) another string inside `for` loop and init it, while the first one is left as `null`.

If I understand your logic correctly it could be something like this:

```
 List<String> titles = new ArrayList<String>();

 for (int i=0; i < jArray.length(); i++){ 
       oneObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
        // Pulling items from the array
        titles.add(oneObject.getString("title"));
    }

setListAdapter ( new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.single_item, titles));
```

Comment: Just to add on... you redeclare oneObjectsItem inside the loop, which creates a new copy of it.. if you get rid of the String before it then it will refer to the one you already declared

Comment: i dont understand what you mean

Comment: Inside the `for` loop there is a line `String oneObjectsItem = oneObject.getString("title");` that defines and initializes a new String on every iteration, which is visible only inside the loop. Somewhere BEFORE the loop you define another String, initialized to `null` and that the one that gets passed to `setListAdapter`

Comment: is this correct     JSONArray jArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("news");
            String oneObjectsItem = null;
      
      for (int i=0; i < jArray.length(); i++)
      {
          JSONObject oneObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
          // Pulling items from the array
       
          String oneObjectsItem1 = oneObject.getString("title");
      
      
   
      }

Comment: what you probably need is to define `List<String>` and populate it inside the loop. then pass it to the ArrayAdapter

Comment: sorry to be a pain but could you post an example i'm a bit lost i moved the string oneObjectsItem out of the for loop and it couldn't find oneObject. i'm struggling to understand the logic. ps thank you for helping me by the way really appreciate it been trying to do it for days

Comment: I'm getting the error oneObjectItem cannot be resolved as a variable

Comment: can you post the whole thing?