# Android getting a string from a for loop into a setlistAdapter

Tags: android, json

hi im expanded a previous question i asked just to make it clearer. i'm trying to get a json feed from a url and then create a list of titles using a list adapter. my json feed consists of a thing called data inside that an array of news and inside that thing called title.

when i run the app it force closes. I've been told its because i have a string inside a for loop and no instance of it outside to go in the adapter. i am new to this so any help would be appreciated heres my code

```
 try{
            // Create a new HTTP Client
            DefaultHttpClient defaultClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            // Setup the get request
            HttpGet httpGetRequest = new HttpGet("jsonfeed");

            // Execute the request in the client
            HttpResponse httpResponse = defaultClient.execute(httpGetRequest);
            // Grab the response
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpResponse.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
            String json = reader.readLine();


            // Instantiate a JSON object from the request response
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);



            JSONArray jArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("news");

            String oneObjectsItem1 = null;
            for (int i=0; i < jArray.length(); i++)
            {
                JSONObject oneObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                // Pulling items from the array

                String oneObjectsItem = oneObject.getString("title");



            }


        } catch(Exception e){
            // In your production code handle any errors and catch the individual exceptions
            e.printStackTrace();
        }





        setListAdapter ( new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.single_item, oneObjectsItem)); 
        ListView list = getListView();
        list.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
```

Comment: paste your json response string too

Comment: Hey looks like you're using my answer to your question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-to-parse-json-in-android/9606629#9606629 , how about you accept it if it was helpful to you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android setlistAdapter error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9623565/android-setlistadapter-error)

Comment: {"code":200,"error":null,"data":{"news":[{"news_id":"8086","title":"Tickets for Player of the Year award on general sale"heres the json response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is not clear since we don't know what you're doing after you get the JSON, here's the proper way to get and handle it, and a possible fix for the string itself. Also, please consider accepting answers that you use, like in your question here: [How to parse JSON in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-to-parse-json-in-android/9606629)

Second of all, you're going over a whole array and creating a new object every time.

**Remove This**

```
String oneObjectsItem1 = null;
for (int i=0; i < jArray.length(); i++)
{
    JSONObject oneObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
    // Pulling items from the array
    String oneObjectsItem = oneObject.getString("title");
}
```

**Use This**

```
JSONArray jArray = MYJSONOBJECT.getJSONArray("JSONARRAYNAME");
ArrayList<String> myTitlesFromMyArray = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int i=0; i < jArray.length(); i++)
{
    JSONObject oneObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
    // TITLE IS IN MY ARRAY I WANT ALL TITLES IN MY LIST OF TITLES
    myTitlesFromMyArray.add(oneObject.getString("title"));
}

// Iterate through the ENTIRE list and do whatever you want with the items in order
for (String p: myTitlesFromMyArray)
{
     // Do something with p
}
```

Also, I think your stream for the json string may come back incomplete, to ensure it is complete change it

**Remove This**

```
String json = reader.readLine();
```

**Use This**

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

String input = null;
while ((input = reader.readLine()) != null)
{
    sb.append(input + "\n");
}
String json = input.toString();
```

Comment: hi thank you so much i will accept everything. this is good use getting an error here String titleFour = myTitlesFromMyArray.get(3);Type mismatch: cannot convert from CharSequence to String

Comment: edited my answer, it's entirely correct what you do with the ArrayList is up to you?

Comment: thanks this helped how  do i get string p into a list adapter

Comment: String newstitles = null;
      // Iterate through the ENTIRE list and do whatever you want with the items in order
      for (String p: myTitlesFromMyArray)
      {
            newstitles=p;
      }
      
  } catch(Exception e){
      // In your production code handle any errors and catch the individual exceptions
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
  
     
     
     
     
     setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.single_item, newstitles}));  
     ListView list = getListView();
  list.setTextFilterEnabled(true);this is wht i've dne with it so far i still can't get it to work

Answer (score 0):

you need to collect your string out from json into an ArrayList and later provide that list object to adapter. see the example below:

```
List<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();

try{
 .
 .
 .
 for (int i=0; i < jArray.length(); i++)
 {
  JSONObject oneObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
  String oneObjectsItem = oneObject.getString("title");

  if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(oneObjectsItem))
    items.add(oneObjectsItem);
 }
}


//and set the list object to your adapter
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.single_item, items);
```

Comment: hi thanks for your help i tried his but its still coming up in red saying create local variable one ObjectsItem

Comment: what do you mean? elaborate your problem

Comment: this it great thanks its not crashing anymore but its not showing anything on screen

Comment: check if your for-loop does produce string items for your listview. you may check this by logging as `Log.i("json", oneObjectsItem);` inside your loop

Comment: hi i've put the log in but ant see it bringing back anything not sure how to use it really